# Char memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

I am writing a program that reads a user input, but I don't want to give any upper limit to it's size, so I've decided to allocate it's memory dynamically like this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char ** INPUT;
  char * inputSize;
  int cl;
  printf("Enter your operation here: \n");
  scanf("%s", INPUT);
  for(cl = 0; INPUT[cl] != '\0'; ++cl);
  inputSize = (char *) malloc((cl + 1) * sizeof(char));

 return 0;
}
```

This program compiles and runs, but after entering the input it terminates with following error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I am just starting to learn about pointers, so I would appreciate someone pointing out mistakes I'm making. Thank you!

Comment: You did not allocate space for INPUT. After you fix that what is the reason for char** ?

Comment: To do what you want (unlimited input line length), you need to read in chunks, and if line does not end by the end of chunk, you need to read more. Once you have read all chunks (to a linked list, for example), then you can allocate a single buffer and combine them (if necessary).

Comment: Oh right I've changed it as before I was just allocating to INPUT with the same error.

Comment: Can you use GNU or POSIX functions, namely [*getline* or *getdelim*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) ? If yes, then use it. If not, then you basically need to re-implement it one way or another.

Comment: Here `scanf("%s", ...` a `char*` is expected. *And* the compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` equals `1` by definition, so using it is useless.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help, I have just used getline, and allocated everything in unsigned_t buffer. That works.